# Sending an automatic email

Tags: android, email

Hi im trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/android/send-email-on-button-click-without-email-chooser/)

I followed all the steps and when i try to execute the app i get the following error:

```
03-14 17:24:19.618 3532-3532/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress.Mail', referenced from method ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress.EnvioMail$SendMail.doInBackground
03-14 17:24:19.618 3532-3532/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 2544 (Lar/com/taxiexpress/taxiexpress/Mail;) in Lar/com/taxiexpress/taxiexpress/EnvioMail$SendMail;
03-14 17:24:19.618 3532-3532/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0001
03-14 17:24:19.618 3532-3532/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress W/dalvikvm: Unable to resolve superclass of Lar/com/taxiexpress/taxiexpress/Mail; (9576)
03-14 17:24:19.618 3532-3532/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress W/dalvikvm: Link of class 'Lar/com/taxiexpress/taxiexpress/Mail;' failed
03-14 17:24:19.618 3532-3532/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress D/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x51e4 at 0x07 in Lar/com/taxiexpress/taxiexpress/EnvioMail$SendMail;.doInBackground
03-14 17:24:19.650 3532-3676/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress W/dalvikvm: threadid=17: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d31b20)
03-14 17:24:19.650 3532-3676/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
                                                                              Process: ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress, PID: 3532
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress.Mail
                                                                                  at ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress.EnvioMail$SendMail.doInBackground(EnvioMail.java:51)
                                                                                  at ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress.EnvioMail$SendMail.doInBackground(EnvioMail.java:34)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
                                                                                  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841) 
03-14 17:24:19.678 3532-3532/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 17:24:19.854 3532-3532/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-14 17:24:20.382 3532-3546/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress I/GMPM: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
03-14 17:27:01.184 3532-3538/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 305K, 3% free 16909K/17288K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
03-14 17:29:19.670 3532-3676/ar.com.taxiexpress.taxiexpress I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3532 SIG: 9
```

could someone tell me what should I check to resolve this issue, thanks in advance.

Comment: `Unable to resolve superclass of Lar/com/taxiexpress/taxiexpress/Mail; (9576)`. What is your `Mail` class extending?

Comment: hi mate mi Mail class like the tutorial extends from javax.mail.Authenticator

Comment: The device does not seem to be finding `javax.mail.Authenticator` for some reason. It may have to do with however you attached the JARs for this stuff to your project. You might consider editing your question and explaining in greater detail how you did that.